# Filter EntityDataSource for DateTime field

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using and EntityDateSource and I add where condition to filter the data at runtime and then bind the grid to the dataSource, but I am getting following error:-

```
The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation.
```

Search condition looks like this:-

```
it.[MyDate]='8/13/2010 00:00:00'
```

Any Idea how this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some thing left in the answer given by VinayC . The following will definately work as it worked for me.

use syntax such as it.[MyDate]= DATETIME '2010-13-8 00:00'

Answer (score 0):

EntityDataSource.Where uses EnttiySQL sytanx. The date time literals need to be specified in *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM* - see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx).

In short, use syntax such as `it.[MyDate]='2010-13-8 00:00'` and you should be ok.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect, since your answer is missing one vital point. As the documentation (which you link to) says, a datetime must be prefixed with DATETIME, thus the correct answer would be that of Sachins post: it.[MyDate]= DATETIME '2010-13-8 00:00'

Answer (score 0):

`Private Sub EntityDataSource1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles EntityDataSource1.Selecting`

`Dim dat As String = Format(CDate(my_Date), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`
  `EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.my_field = CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & dat & "', 102)) "`

`End Sub`

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable